# What is a library that provides a very simple, universal usage of Naives Bayes classifier?

Tags: python

I know that NLTK has this.  But...is that only for NLP?
Is there a library that specializes in classification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/pybayes/

Answer (score 0):

Reverend may be another nice option: http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodReverend